# Facebook, what is the privacy setting of my app post?

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk, facebook-permissions

I am creating an iOS app within which, the users can share posts about their whereabouts.
The app MUST verify that a post that was made within it is made with a privacy setting that is not "SELF" or "CUSTOM". (specifically, either "My Friends" or "Public")

I was reading around and came across some info:
[This artcile](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/post) shows exactly how to do this, providing I have the `read_stream` permission, but for this app - `read_stream` is just a bit too intrusive.
The app **does not need** to actually read any of the posts of the users.

All I need is to be figure out how I can only read my **own app's** posts' privacy settings, without violating facebook's terms for "read_stream". As they specifically stated:

> This permission is granted to apps building a Facebook-branded client on platforms where Facebook is not already available. For example, Android and iOS apps will not be approved for this permission. In addition, Web, Desktop and TV apps will not be granted this permission.

As said, this ability sounds a little like get too much or get nothing at all. 
Is there a midpoint there for this app?

Comment: Why “must” the app do such a thing? If you are thinking of rewarding the user for making posts in _any way_ – that would violate Platform Policies.

Comment: @CBroe, what platform policies?

Comment: Seriously …? [Facebook Platform Policies](https://developers.facebook.com/policy) – you should read them, if you want to develop an app on the platform …

Comment: The privacy level is not available by design (the user can change it later anyways), and as @CBroe pointed out, please follow the platform policies.